# Localhost/PhpMyAdmin 403 forbidden

Tags: apache

I have `Windows 10` and installed the `wamp server 2.1` and I can't access the `PHPMyAdmin` site. Within the `phpmyadmin.conf` file I have:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#        Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all    
#   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all 
# 

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And I don't know how to fix this so I can see the `PHPMyAdmin` site.

**EDIT**

Now I have `This site can’t be reached` as the Apache service won't start. The `Error log` is as follows: http://pastebin.com/ws4EnjCq

Comment: try this (https://www.digifloor.com/simple-steps-fix-403-forbidden-errors-wamp-server-28)

Comment: @madhankumar I tried that but now it won't start after I've restarted the server, the Apache service won't start

Comment: mm look at log file. you can find what problem actually you facing.

Comment: @madhankumar I'll add it into the question

Comment: Check for any spelling mistakes. If you not getting any solution then try this link (http://askubuntu.com/questions/483297/why-do-i-always-get-a-403-error-with-phpmyadmin) or go with xampp

Comment: Can you verify that you have no entries `127.0.0.1` in your Windows `hosts` file? Also, can you verify that no other program is holding port `80`. Some of the more commons issues must be cleared first... also, some of your links appear "impossible" such as `C:\\wamp\\www\\ ` you have double `\ ` in a row. Finally, if everything is right, are you using any other form of access block such as `.htaccess` that could deny you?

Comment: @Bonatti How do I verify I have no entries `127.0.0.1` on my `hosts` file?

Comment: [the hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) is a plain text file, that reduces your need for DNS resolutions... in (usually) `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` you will find it. copy/paste that file so that you have a backup, then edit with a notepad. Search for a line with `127.0.0.1 aFakeSite`.... localhost, self, loopback and similar names are usually fine. However, suspicious names use this exploit to gather PC information or reroute your browser queries.